# Different outputs from the read() functions of serial port

Tags: c#, serial-port

I'm trying to use the output from a serial to write them into a text file for an experiment and trigger the device continuously using the serial port commands. Here is the sample code I'm using to to test the read() functions which all work differently and I'm unable to understand why.

I want to be able to use the bytestoread prperty to keep checkign for any output in the serial to write to my text file.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
        SerialPort port = new SerialPort("COM4", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
        port.Open();
        port.DtrEnable = true;
        port.RtsEnable = true;
        port.NewLine = "\r";
        port.Handshake = Handshake.RequestToSend;
        if (port.IsOpen) { Console.WriteLine("port is now open"); } else { Console.WriteLine("port not opened correctly"); }
        port.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port_DataReceived);
        port.Write("T");
        Console.WriteLine("bytes to read : {0}",port.BytesToRead);
        Console.WriteLine("return value form .read function : {0}",port.Read(buffer,0,20));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
        Console.WriteLine(sp.ReadTo("\r"));

    }

}
```

the output is

port is now open
bytes to read : 0
return value form .read function : 1
199.0,+238.0,091

Can somebody help me understand why the port.bytestoread returns 0 and port.Read() which has to return the count returns only one but the readTo() functiosn returns the actaul output?

Answer (score 1):

It is because the `DataReceived` event handler is called from a background thread.  This thread doesn't call your `port_DataReceived` until *after* `Console.WriteLine("bytes to read : {0}",port.BytesToRead);`  is called

Comment: How can I use the bytestoread property in that case? Should I put teh bytestoRead within teh eventhandler>

Comment: how do you want to use it?  It tells you how many bytes are available to be read at the time BytesToRead is called, if you call it and there are no bytes to read, it will be zero...  If all you want is to show how my bytes are read, then yes, put it in the event handler.

Comment: I tried putting it in the eventhandler and it shows that there are 17 bytes to read. I think I can work with that. Thanks.

Comment: Okay, there are 17 bytes to read... is that a problem?  Again, data is received asynchronously.  This means that between the call to BytesToRead and the call to Read, data can be received--which means whatever BytesToRead says may be different than the quantity of what you actually read.